# Eigenvalues vs.matrix sparsity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

For an n X n matrix whose entries are constrained to be in some [x,y], is the maximum absolute eigenvalue of the matrix a function of its sparsity?

Is there a closed-form expression that states this function?

Comment: What is "sparsity" for you? A percentage of zero entries, or a precise sparsity pattern?

Comment: A percentage of zero entries, for starters.