# What is the largest possible operator norm of a sparse (0,1)-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107121/eigenvalues-vs-matrix-sparsity), I was wondering about the following problem:

Consider all $n\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices with $k$ ones.  Which of these matrices has the largest operator norm?  And how does this largest possible operator norm behave with $n$ and $k$?

If any progress has already been made on this problem, I assume it's in the guise of directed graphs.  For the case of symmetric matrices with zero diagonal, which graphs give the largest possible largest eigenvalue?  $(k/n)$-regular graphs?

Comment: Sure, Survit. That is the Hilbert-Schmidt, which dominates the operator norm, and the norms are the same for rank one operators. More generally, $k^{1/2}$ is the right answer for all $k \le n$ for the same reason--put all the ones in one column. I guess when $n^2 \ge k > n$ you get the max when you fill up as many columns as possible with ones and put the left over ones into one column.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I realized that my question was obvious, which is why I deleted my comment a few seconds after posting it :-)  -- suVRit

Answer (score 5):

If $k=ab$ with $a\leq n$ and $b\leq n$, then an $a \times b$ rectangle of $1$s surrounded by $0$s hits the optimal matrix norm of $\sqrt{k}$.  Otherwise, $\sqrt{k}$ is not achievable, but it's clear that one can get very close to $\sqrt{k}$ with very close to a rectangle.

A $k/n$-regular graph has a largest eigenvalue of $k/n$ which is not that great. A better thing to do is a complete graph on about $\sqrt{k}$ vertices plus $n-\sqrt{k}$ isolated vertices, which gives a largest eigenvalue of about $\sqrt{k}$.